# Trigger a Jquery function that has $this. onload and onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Trigger a Jquery function that has $this. on window load and on click

```
function get_div_id(){
var f_id = $(this).attr("id");
alert(f_id);
}

$(window).load(function(){ 
get_div_id();
});

$('.divs_same_class_diferent_id').click(function() {
get_div_id();
});
```

As you can deduce, this will not work, but you have an idea of what I'm trying to do, right?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get the `id` of all elements of a given class? To do what with? Store in an array, use in another function? Something else entirely?

Comment: Hi David, I'm trying to get the div id, on click and a default div id on window load.

Comment: And which `<div>` should be the 'default' on page-load, the first, last, another specific element or one at random?

Comment: Thank you David. It should be an specific element.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on where that code is it may be running prior to the DOM being created in which case you're attempting to bind event listeners to elements that do not yet exist.  try this:

```
function get_div_id(){

  var f_id = $(this).attr("id");
  alert(f_id);

}

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.divs_same_class_diferent_id').click(get_div_id);
  // notice no anonymous function, this works because
  // we're passing in the function object for get_div_id

});
```

Comment: And, instead of $(document).ready(function(){...} use directly $(functon () {....}) which is shorter.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was trying to do. But what if I want to trigger the same function on window load? How can I pass an default div id value?

Comment: You could add that function inside the callback to $(document).ready and then use the call method of the function object which sets the context of "this", i.e. get_div_id.call(myElementReference)